# Default configuration iptables, how to avoid to be blocked when flushing tables?

Tags: linux, iptables, iptables-persistent

I have this base for [iptables](/questions/tagged/iptables) when I have a new server to configure :

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# Keep state.
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Loop device.
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow PING from remote hosts.
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# allow ssh port 22
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# allow foobar public IP
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 9.8.7.6 -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing trafic
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o enp8s0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

I load this file with `iptable-restore < file`.

The issue is that when I flush with `iptables -F`, I get blocked.

What I have to do to avoid to be blocked ?

Comment: quick internet search revealed that you have to set INPUT,  OUTPUT and FORWARD connections to ACCEPT .... then flush the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A detailled way, is to set `ACCEPT` all policy to all connections before flushing :

```
iptables -P INPUT    ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT   ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD  ACCEPT
```

Then :

```
iptables -F
```

Answer (score 1):

As in the comment below the question, before flushing make sure that the default policies are not locking you out.

Another way to go is not to use `iptables -F` but have another rule file for restoring the basic state. In fact there is a separate `iptables` family command, which is safe in the respect of checking whether no such lockout takes place. It is `iptables-apply` and is used similarly to `iptable-restore`, but check its `man` pages for differences and details.